# Jquery slideUp, Deattach, appendTo and the slidedown

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to make an element fade out, then move to another place and then fade in again.

**I tried:**

```
$(elem).slideUp().delay(500).detach().appendTo('#div').delay(500).slideDown();
```

And **I tried:**

```
$(elem).slideUp();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(elem).detach().appendTo('#div');
  },1300)
$(elem).slideDown()
```

Nothing seem to work the appendto function fires before any other...

*Any Ideas?*

Thanks.

Comment: Use a complete callback with the `slideUp()` (read the doco). Note also that you don't need `detach()` because if used with a single target `appendTo()` will *move* your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the completion callback to sequence your operations:

### Simple

### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cnft0w4v/2/)

```
(function($) {
    $('.start').on('click', function(event) {
        var elem = $('.from');
        elem.slideUp(400, function() {
            elem.appendTo('.to');
            elem.slideDown();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

- jQuery calls the callback when the slide finishes.
- Appending an element *moves* it if it was already in the document, no need to detach.
- 400 is in milliseconds. Change it to change the slide speed. You can pass a value to the `slideDown` to control its speed.

### Powerful

Create a jquery extension that can simultaneously animate multiple elements into multiple targets.

## [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a9dw43cz/1/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.animateInto = function(target, callback) {
        target = $(target);
        return this.each(function(i) {
            var elem = $(this),
                complete = 0;
            elem.slideUp(400, function() {
                elem.appendTo(target.eq(i % target.length));
                elem.slideDown(function() {
                    if (++complete === elem.length)
                        callback && callback();
                });
            });
        });
    };
    
    $('.start').on('click', function(event) {
        $('.from').animateInto('.to');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many jQuery functions take a callback method as a parameter. For example [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/#slideUp-duration-complete) can do this, and it might look something like this:

```
$(elem).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(elem).detach().appendTo('#div').delay(500).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only animation methods are placed in jQuery's effects queue.

`appendTo()` is not an animation method, but you can use jQuery's [**queue()**](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method to add it to the effects queue:

```
var elem = $('#ball');

$(elem)
  .slideUp()
  .delay(500)
  .queue(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#div').dequeue();
  })
  .delay(500)
  .slideDown();
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var elem = $('#ball');

$(elem)
  .slideUp()
  .delay(500)
  .queue(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#div').dequeue();
  })
  .delay(500)
  .slideDown();
```

```css
#ball {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ball">

</div>

<div id="div">
  
</div>
```